# Need to open and save Excel file before reading it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, epplus

I have a method were I create an Excelsheet. When the file is created I need to open it and save it manually in Excel before I can read it with Excel Data Reader. If I open and save the exact same file without changeing anything I can read it like I wan't it to work. Does anyone know how I can:

a) Save it properly when creating the file (using EPPlus)?

or

b) Open the already created file and save it properly by using C# before I try to read it?

My create method:

```
public void CreateAnnuityExcelSheet(List<Calculation> cList, FormCollection form, int DTCyear)
{
    string fileName = "test";
    string path = @"C:\ExcelFiles\" + fileName + ".xlsx"; //Path for the file
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(path);
    info.Directory.Create(); //If C:\ExcelFiles does not exist, create it
    if (!info.Exists)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(info))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(fileName);

            //Filling the worksheet with values here...

            package.SaveAs(info);
        }
    }
}
```

My read method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowExcelFile(GetExcel model)
{
    List<Calculation> cList = new List<Calculation>();
    DataSet result = null;
    var file = model.Files[0];
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // .xlsx
        IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(file.InputStream);

        reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
        result = reader.AsDataSet();
        reader.Close();

        var PV = Convert.ToDecimal(data.Table.Rows[1][6]); //Works fine if the file is opened and saved in Excel. Else null..
        //Work with the dataset here. When the file is not opened and saved it gets null everywhere. Else it works fine
    }
    return View("ShowExcelFile", model);
}
```

I have also tried using WriteAllBytes instead of using package.SaveAs():

```
byte[] data = package.GetAsByteArray();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, data);
```

This gets my the exact same result. I still need to open and save the file manually.

Comment: Instead of using package.SaveAs(info), use package.Save(). You already have the file open by new ExcelPackage(info). My guess is the reason why you have to manually open and save is because the excel document markup isn't created properly.

Comment: You mean the code for filling the cells with formulas etc?

Comment: Not really. Do yourself a favor, create and save an empty excel file using excel. Right click it, open with Notepad. And you'll see what I'm talking about. The meta data that makes an excel file an excel file is most probably not written to the file. In any case, have you tried package.Save() instead of package.SaveAs(info) ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that. Same result. Will check it out in notepad

Comment: Hello krillezzz. Did you ever got to solve this problem?

Comment: @ManuelReis unfortunately not. The problem was when opening the Excel file manually and closed it Excel it self added some styling which made the file bigger

Comment: For me it removes some commas when I open and save the file manually, allowing to import the file. I will inspect the problem further, if I find something I'll be sure to put it here.

Comment: @krillezzz I ended up using another reader (openXML), and it works fine now. There is probably some bug in IExcelDataReader that does not deal well with Excel metadata.

Comment: @ManuelReis Thanks. Will remember this until next time :)